# Flash AS2 if (Key.getCode() == Key.ENTER) doesn't work?

Tags: flash

Help, Im new to AS2 (Flash In general), And Im trying to make a basic menu who is controlled by the keyboard. here is my code

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
{  
if(_root.menu1._currentframe==1)
{
  _root.menu1.gotoAndStop(2);
}
}

if(Key.isDown(Key.UP))
{  
if(_root.menu1._currentframe==2)
{
  _root.menu1.gotoAndStop(1);
}
}

if (Key.getCode() == Key.ENTER) 
{  
if(_root.menu1._currentframe==1)
{
gotoAndStop("stage1");
}
   else{ gotoAndStop("stage2"); }
}
}
```

The up and down button works fine, but the enter does not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you testing your swf ( standalone flash player, the browser, your IDE ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be working, sometime the `Key.ENTER` event doesn't always show up when you're testing in the Flash Environment or IDE.

Try publishing your code and running it in a browser, maybe add a dynamic text field or use the console to debug.

You can also using a keyListener Object rather than an enterFrame event. If you want to try it, try adding this code to a frame in the timeline

```
//import the external interface code
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

// Create a key listener object;
var keyListener:Object = new Object();

// Add the onKeyDown functionality
keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {

    // Convert incoming key presses to Ascii 
    var keyLetter = String.fromCharCode(Key.getAscii());
    // get the Key code
    var keyCode =   Key.getCode();
    // output the keyCode and keyLetter to the browser console / developer tools / firebug
    // When testing in a browser press F12 on the keyboard to show them
    // make sure you click on the SWF movie to get the focus then press keys
    ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "["+keyCode+"] "+keyLetter)
    // trace this so we can compare in Flash
    trace( "["+keyCode+"] "+keyLetter);

    if (Key.isDown(Key.ENTER)) {
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "ENTER key pressed!")
    }

};

// Add the listener
Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK,function():void{});
can you convert the above code to AS2.0?
The above code works fine on the AS3.0.
disables the right cli

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).